# Close the app programmatically (know package name)

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-intent, android-package-managers

I use the following code snippet to launch an app on device:

```
Context mContext = getContext();
String packageName = getPackageName(); //the app to launch

Intent mIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);
if(mIntent!=null){
     mContext.startActivity(mIntent);
}
```

It works, the app get launched, however, I don't figure out a way to close the launched app by using the `packageName`.

How to close the launched app if I only know the package name?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot close another app. Only the system can do that.

But if you are also the author of that other app, you could create a receiver in that app's activities that accepts an intent that tells it to finish() the activities.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot close other application from your app.your problem has a workaround,after starting app based on package name you may send home intent which will give same experience to user.

```
  Intent mIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);
    if(mIntent!=null){
         mContext.startActivity(mIntent);
    }
//sleep for 250ms or whatever time using handler
    Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(startMain);
```